# Warn users that are posting code on meta

Tags: feature-request, meta, code-block

I'm pretty sure the parser is able to recognize code in the body of a post.

Should we give a warning to users that are trying to post some code on Meta ?

> [What is meta, how does it work ?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)
>
> This question contains some code and is unlikely to belong on meta.stackoverlow.com. Did you mean to post this question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)?

Yes, some users might have valid questions with code in it like questions about the code parser or even bug reports about the code parser. They could simply click proceed and ask their question anyway. But the vast majority of questions with code in the body end up closed within seconds, stay on hold in the feed bugging us there.  Giving a warning to the user would make them stop and maybe .. *maybe*.. realize that something is wrong with their post.

---

From the comments :

Users should be redirected to the FAQ insteadt to make sure we don't just *transfer* our problem to SO.

Comment: But most questions containing code that end up on Meta these days are really, really, really bad, as it's really tough to end up here now. What do we want to tell them to do instead? Because it likely shouldn't be going to Stack Overflow, either

Comment: @Pëkka Well since it's kind of hard to tell if a question is bad just with a bot,we could change up the message a little bit to say something like : Since you were posting some code on meta, maybe you are not understanding the fundamentals of this network. We recommend you read the Help section before posting this question on StackOverflow as this question might not receive positive feedback from the community.

Comment: Link them to [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) instead of linking to the SO homepage.

Answer (score 6):

That's not a bad idea, but I suggest to disable this feature after a user has a total question score of 15 on Meta, because if a user has a total question score of 15, I suppose that he/she knows how Meta works.

Comment: Yes this is way better than what I first thought (Blocking code to -15 rep users)

Comment: Be careful with this though; if you just block it you're more likely to just have lots of people posting code that's not formatted as code, instead of just not posting code.

Comment: Man, Servy, you are ALWAYS assuming the worst!  You're a "glass is half full" guy, aren't you?  Or, probably more of a "glass is half full and there's no more beer in the fridge".  I don't think people spend as much time as you think trying to screw up SO.